# material datepicker icon configuration

Tags: angular-material, angular8

I need to change material date picker icon and also I want date toggle to happen on clicking input box .Current behaviour is on clicking existing datepicker icon the date will be toggled.

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput #startInput [matDatepicker]="startPicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
           (dateInput)="startDateChangeEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="startDateChangeEvent('change', $event)">
           <mat-hint style="color:red">{{startDateErrorMsg}}</mat-hint>
           <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="startPicker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #startPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1):

To change material date picker icon you can add `mat-icon` instead of `mat-datepicker-toggle` and for toggle to happen on clicking input box you have to `(click)="startPicker.open()"` in input like given below:

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <input matInput #startInput [matDatepicker]="startPicker" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"
    (click)="startPicker.open()"
           (dateInput)="startDateChangeEvent('input', $event)" (dateChange)="startDateChangeEvent('change', $event)">
           <mat-hint style="color:red">{{startDateErrorMsg}}</mat-hint>
           <span matSuffix>
             <mat-icon>home</mat-icon>
           </span>
    <mat-datepicker #startPicker></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```